# How to filter collection by OR condition?

Tags: magento-1.8, mysql, query, convert

I have two 'Yes/No' attributes created for products in my store. I want to get the product collection of products whose at least one attribute is set to yes. I've searched the web, but many websites mentions OR condition against a single attribute.

For the sake of clearance I'll mention the relevant SQL statement which I want to convert in Magento way,

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE attribute1 = true OR attribute2 = true;
```

Any suggestions would appreciate.

Answer (score 6):

you can perform `OR` condition in this manner

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute'=>'attribute1', 'eq' => '1'),
        array('attribute'=>'attribute2', 'eq' => '1'),
    )
);
```

Refer this [***link***](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I already tried this. But it results as AND condition not OR

Comment: @Sukheshini This will return or condition

Comment: If you create an AND, then you have one level to less in your array()